# Proof of an inequality involving the $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms and the $\ell_0$ "norm"

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

> For any non-zero vector $x$,
>   $$
> \lVert x\rVert_0 \geq \frac{\lVert x\rVert_1^2}{\lVert x\rVert_2^2}
> $$

I am trying to prove this inequality using the definitions of the $\ell_0$ "norm" (the number of none zero elements in the vector) and the definitions of the $\ell_1$  and $\ell_2$ norms; but I'm getting nowhere... I tried using $1$ or $n$ to prove it but it didn't help..

Comment: (soapbox time) _please_ don't use the term "$\ell_0$ norm", and please encourage everyone around you to stop doing so as well. The cardinality function is _not_ a norm, and calling it such causes a lot of people confusion. I am in a position to experience this confusion firsthand. When the term $\ell_0$ norm was originally coined, it was made absolutely clear that it is an abuse of notation. Now nobody bothers to issue that caveat anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rearrange the elements of $x$ so that the nonzeros are in entries $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $n$, where $n=\| x \|_{0}$.  .You can rewrite the inequality as

$n(x_{1}^{2}+\ldots+x_{n}^{2}) \geq (|x_{1}|+\ldots +|x_{n}|)^{2}$.

After taking the square root of both sides, this is equivalent to the well-known inequality for the 1-norm and 2-norm,

$\sqrt{n}\| x \|_{2} \geq \| x \|_{1}.$

This well-known inequality is easy to prove using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality with $|x|$ and a vector of all ones.

Comment: My soapbox comment above applies to you too, friend ;-)

Comment: I've given up on fighting that battle, along with the abuse of the matrix 1 and 2-norms vs. the sum of the absolute values of the entries and the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Ha ha! I will never give up!

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct consequence of Cauchy—Schwarz: writing $\mathbf{1}_{\{a > 0\}}$ for the indicator of $\{a>0\}$,

$$
\mathbf{1}_{\{a > 0\}} = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if } a>0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
we have
$$\begin{align}
\lVert x\rVert_1 = \sum_{i} \lvert x_i\rvert = \sum_{i} \lvert x_i\rvert \mathbf{1}_{\{x_i > 0\}} &\leq
\sqrt{\sum_{i} \lvert x_i\rvert^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i} \mathbf{1}_{\{x_i > 0\}}^2}
= \sqrt{\sum_{i} \lvert x_i\rvert^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i} \mathbf{1}_{\{x_i > 0\}}}\\
&= \lVert x\rVert_2\sqrt{\rVert x\rVert_0}
\end{align}$$
where the only inequality is Cauchy—Schwarz, and we used the fact that $\mathbf{1}_{\{x_i > 0\}}=\mathbf{1}_{\{x_i > 0\}}^2$ for all $i$ (as $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$).

Squaring and rearranging gives the result.