# Is $\ell^{p-1}$ a subspace of $\ell^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm studying Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications by Erwin Kreyszig. In Chapter 2, section 2.4, while solving exercise, this question came to my mind, but I can't figure it out, please help me...

If $\ell^p$ is metric space, where $1≤p<∞$, then show that whether $\ell^{p-1}$ is subspace of $\ell^p$ or not? If it is not a subspace, give reason.

Comment: Although it is tempting when asking a first Question to put as much of the problem statement in the title as you can, this is not generally possible.  In any case, use the greater amount of space available in the body of the Question to give a full problem statement (setup and goal) as well as supplying the context (e.g. where you encountered the problem, Kreyszig's book in this case).  Also note that [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) can be used in your posts here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $p=1$, this doesnt really make sense unless you want to be bold and tell the world what $0^0$ is.

In general, let $0<s<t<\infty$ and let $(x_n)\in\ell^s$. Then $\sum_n|x_n|^s<\infty$. In particular $|x_n|^s\to0$ and thus we have some $n_0$ such that $|x_n|<1$ for $n\ge n_0$. Now since $s<t$, we have that $$|x_n|^t=|x_n|^s|x_n|^{t-s}=|x_n|^s\cdot\text{ number less than 1}\le |x_n|^s$$ for all $n\ge n_0$. thus
$$\sum_n|x_n|^t=\sum_{n=1}^{n_0}|x_n|^t+\sum_{n>n_0}|x_n|^t\le \text{finite number}+\sum_{n>n_0}|x_n|^s<\infty$$
so $(x_n)\in\ell^t$, i.e. $\ell^s\subset\ell^t$.

For $1< p<\infty$, take $t=p$ and $s=p-1$.

Comment: Sometimes $\ell^0$ is used for the space of sequences [with finitely many nonzero entries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2512461/proof-of-an-inequality-involving-the-ell-1-and-ell-2-norms-and-the-ell-0), so a case could be made for the inclusion when $p=1$ without resorting to $0^0$.

Comment: In measure theory $L_0$ is the space of all measurable functions that are finite a.sd. $\ell_0$ may be identified with $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  For the OP it probably is better to ask whether $\ell_p\subset\ell_{p'}$ whenever p<p'$.

Comment: @hardmath I have never come across this notation; I know this space as $c_{00}$, but this is obviously a subspace of any $\ell^p$ space.

Comment: @OliverDíaz what does a.sd. stand for?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: It is a typo. I means to write a.s. (almost surely)

Comment: Also, why the downvote? did you find my comment on $0^0$ arrogant? Because it was meant to be a joke

Comment: @JustDroppedIn: No, it is $\mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the set of all numerical sequences.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Ah okay I got confused with a.s. 0. Thanks

Comment: |xn|t=|xn|s|xn|t−s=|xn|s⋅ number less than 1≤|xn|s

                     I'm not getting this, kindly explain a bit... @JustDroppedIn

Comment: @SyedBilalHaider what is it that confuses you?